# Sharing a bank of contacts

Tags: iphone, contacts, sharing, file-sharing, contacts.app

Is it possible to share multiple contacts in a similar fashion to the way that you would share a single contact from contacts.app? Specifically is there a way to expediently share the list as well as, once received, add the list to the contacts.app on the other persons phone?

Answer (score 1):

You can export a group of contacts.

So first create a group, then add contacts to it. Theres no menuoption for it, but you can rigthclick on the group and select Export vCard-group…

Or you can select desired contacts to export, File -> Export… -> Export vCard-card…

This will give you one vCard-file containing one or more contacts.

Then you can share the vCard file as you wish.